# Disabled drop down not showing value in ie 9 using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am displaying a value like

```
<tr ng-repeat ="bus in buses">
<td><select ><option > {{bus.type}}</option></select>
</td>
</tr>
```

I want to display the already selected list of drop downs in a disabled manner.

In chrome and firefox, it is working fine. But it is showing like this {{bus.type}} in ie 9 while displaying in screen.`enter code here`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular JS not working with IE9 but works with other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567729/angular-js-not-working-with-ie9-but-works-with-other-browsers)

Comment: MY TOTAL APPLICATION IS WORKING EXCEPT DISABLED DROP DOWN

Comment: only disbled drop down not displaying scott marcus

Comment: And, that's why the comment reads *"Possible"* duplicate..... It's meant to give you something to go look at that could be relevant. It's not meant to be the answer.